# Issue for restricting SSH access from a Windows AD Group (using sssd)

Tags: ssh, windows, active-directory, sssd

I joined a ubuntu 16.04 server to my Windows AD for SSH authentication. It works fine until I want to restrict access to a specific group with sssd

here's the content of my /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
domains = my.domain.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/my.domain.com]
ad_domain = my.domain.com
krb5_realm = MY.DOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
simple_allow_users = $
access_provider = ad
ad_access_filter = memberOf=CN=DockerLinuxUser,OU=DockerLinux,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
```

I also tried to use thie query without success

```
ad_access_filter = (&(memberOf=CN=LinuxAdmins,OU=DockerLinux,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)(unixHomeDirectory=*))
```

When ad_access-filter is commented SSH work. When enabled, I cannot SSH the linux server anymore.

I basically followed this walkthrough : [Join Ubuntu 16.04 into Active Directory Domain](http://ricktbaker.com/2017/11/08/ubuntu-16-with-active-directory-connectivity/)

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can give an example.  In our sssd.conf, we start with the general ldap_search_base parameter. You need to know the names of the acceptable user categories, but suppose this one lets in everybody from your organization

```
ldap_search_base = ou=friends,dc=ou,dc=edu???ou=groups,dc=ou,dc=edu??ldap_group_name = uid
```

These are written in an impossibly long line. I don't know how to punctuate them.

To limit the range of users that can get in, we add ON THE END additional requirements. This says we don't want to allow people who are not current employees (no oldWorkers in personPrimayAffiliation) and the user accounts have to be found in any of the groups that begin "grpname_" or "project_admin".

```
ldap_search_base = ou=friends,dc=ou,dc=edu??(!(personPrimaryAffiliation=oldWorkers))?ou=groups,dc=ou,dc=edu??(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(|(cn=grpname_*)(cn=project_admin)))
```

The key bit here is that you need to know the magic words that your organization server uses to refer to users and groups. Start with the general thing that lets everybody in, then add restrictions.

Our config file has krb5_realm and krb5_server similar to yours.  Maybe this won't exactly help  your case, but perhaps it gives you a hint.